# Disposing a Thread in JDK 1.6+

Tags: java

In simple. How to stop and then dispose a thread in JDK 1.6 or 1.7? Javadoc say stop() is deprecated. What is the proper ways to stop/end and then dispose a thread?

Comment: see this oracle [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)

Comment: One more thing, you can not dispose a thread. The GC will take care of that, after you stopped the thread(as running threads will never be GCd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot stop/kill a thread in Java. What you can actually do is to check periodically for some condition and then return from `run()` method which means finishing the thread. Some blocking calls (e.g. [`Thread.sleep()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29)) support interruption by throwing [`InterruptedException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html) whenever another thread interrupts it with [`threadToBeInterrupted.interrupt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) method.

You can check the interruption status periodically (in case of no blocking calls) by either the instance method [`Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted%28%29) or the static method [`Thread.interrupted()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted%28%29). The latter clears the interruption status.

Comment: ... or call some interruptible operations and properly support the interrupt.

Comment: Thank you. Can't +1 - not enough rep

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29

Call thread.interrupt() - that should do what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks! Can't +1 - not enough rep

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that. I assume you have some sort of loop in your `run()` method. To leave/exit the thread you just have to break out of the loop. Now the thing is: how to break out of that loop? There are several ways, for example:

- Interrupt the Thread
- Use some `boolean` expression that will be tested on each loop iteration
- Use poison objects.

You could use a `boolean` to indicate the thread should finish like:

```
volatile boolean stopThread;
...
void run() {
...
  while(!Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted() && !stopThread) {
    // do some stuff
  }
}

public void stopThread() {
  stopThread = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - can't +1 - 6 more rep needed. But what's poison objects?

Comment: @MaueelB consider you process elements out of a queue in your thread. After you have taken the element out of the queue you call some method (say: `myQueueItem.isPoisoned()`) to test if it is a poison object. If it is a poison object you break out of the threads loop. So to stop the thread, you just have to add a *poisoned* element into the queue.